# Convert pure javascript script to a class component in react

Tags: reactjs, data-conversion

i'm having this javascript snippet with html tags and i must adjust it in jsx for react. How to convert the onLoadEvent function and the form

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Title</title> 
<script language="Javascript" > 
function OnLoadEvent(){ 
document.threedfrom.submit(); 
}
</script>
</head> 
<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();" > 
<form name="123123" action="url" method="POST"> 
<textarea style="display: none"name="PaReq"> 
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="ew" value="1">Hlleo
<input type="hidden" name="MD" value="testtest"> 
<noscript>
  <p align="center" class="main">Testing</p>
  <p align="center" class="main"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</noscript>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work, you should **think in React**!

That means that you should always keep in mind that React components act in the virtual DOM and the most reliable way to handle the form submission is to keep your form in Virtual DOM as a *React Component*.

Instead of using `onLoad` event you should use `lifecycle` events in React that also corresponds to the virtual DOM. In the example, I used `componentDidMount` to determine the moment when the root component is mounted (loaded) in the virtual DOM.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {

  state = {
    termUrl: 'http://www.url.gr/return.php',
    md: 'NBGTEST000000412',
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onSubmit({
      termUrl: this.state.termUrl,
      md: this.state.md,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.props.onSubmit({
      termUrl: this.state.termUrl,
      md: this.state.md,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        name="threedfrom"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <h3>Form</h3>
        <textarea style={{ display: 'none' }} name="PaReq"></textarea>
        <span>*Mετά τον ACS για το capture του PARes</span>
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="TermUrl"
          value={this.state.termUrl}
        />
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="MD"
          value={this.state.md}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
 
}


class App extends React.Component {

  submit = (values) => {
    console.log('Submitting', values);
    const url = 'https://accreditation.datacash.com/acs-nbgs2a_i';
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: values,
    })
    .then((resp) => { console.log('Got response', resp); })
    .catch((err) => { console.error('Got error', err); })
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <h2>React App</h2>
        <Form onSubmit={this.submit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Example</title> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<div id="react"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great...but how can we handle the onLoad event inside components?

Comment: In React, you should use `lifecycle` events like `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount`, etc to determine when the Component is loaded. The reason is that React Component act in the Virtual DOM, not the Real DOM

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the textarea is being used, but here is an example to get you started:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    termUrl: 'http://www.url.gr/return.php',
    md: "NBGTEST000000412"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //document.threedfrom.submit(); 
  }
  
  handleSubmit = () => {
    // Make api call using your preferred package
    axios({
      url: 'https://accreditation.datacash.com/acs-nbgs2a_i',
      method: 'POST',
      data: this.state
    });
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea style={{display: "none"}} name="PaReq" />
        <p align="center" class="main">Testing</p>
        <p align="center" class="main"><button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Nice!!! :) One question...why do you comment out the  document.threedfrom.submit();

Comment: Because it was causing an error in the test snippet because `document.threedform` doesn't exist. You should uncomment it in your app.

Comment: Because it's mandatory to use this auto submit do you know how can we do it?